# Prevent autofill suggestion from chrome browser stored addresses in Asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

Recently, I am facing one problem in Chrome. Can anyone expert help?

If I use 'Email' word as label then it's give me email suggestion stored in chrome browser (chrome://settings/addresses).

[image]

If I remove 'Email' label then it's work fine.

[image]

Source:

[image]

**I want to prevent address suggestion box.**

Note: AutoCompleteType or autocomplete="off" does not work.

**Updated**: After some research and investigation, this issue raise because the label contain keyword as 'Email' so it's fetched value from email stored in browser itself.

Comment: Can you show us part of your code because this @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, Model.Email, new { autocomplete = "off"}) should work

Comment: This is a browser related issue and you cannot control this form code. Defining the type of text box can help.

Comment: @ClaudioCorchez Question Updated. Actually I am using webform. This is a user control with one textbox. `<div class="calendar">
<div><asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" Width="100px" CssClass="form-control date-validate" autocomplete="off"/></div>
</div>`

Comment: @JitendraG2 use autcomplete="false" , I know is strange but autcomplete="off" is ignored by many browsers, this is a bug and the false is a workaround. You can put in the autocomplete every string you want and it should do the trick. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=468153#c164

Comment: @ClaudioCorchez Thanks. I will do it but it can't resolve my issue.

Answer (score 2):

`<form autocomplete="off">` for old browsers and add `autocomplete="new-password"` on input field